# Unable to flutter simple flutter app on mac OS X El Capitan Version 10.11.6 (15G22010)

Tags: android, macos, flutter

I installed flutter by first downloading the **SDK** from [HERE](https://storage.googleapis.com/flutter_infra/releases/stable/macos/flutter_macos_v1.12.13+hotfix.5-stable.zip), unzipping then permanently adding the env variables :

```
vim ~/.bash_profile
export PATH="$PATH:/Volumes/path/to/flutter/bin"
```

Then confirm :

```
`which flutter` === ***/path/to/flutter/bin/flutter**
```

**`$ flutter doctor -v`**

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, v1.12.13+hotfix.5, on Mac OS X 10.11.6 15G22010, locale en)
    • Flutter version 1.12.13+hotfix.5 at /Volumes/RevBigData/rev_programs/rev_mac/rev_dev/rev_flutter/flutter
    • Framework revision 27321ebbad (6 days ago), 2019-12-10 18:15:01 -0800
    • Engine revision 2994f7e1e6
    • Dart version 2.7.0


[!] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 28.0.3)
    • Android SDK at /Volumes/RevBigData/rev_programs/rev_mac/rev_android/android_sdks/android_sdk
    • Android NDK location not configured (optional; useful for native profiling support)
    • Platform android-28, build-tools 28.0.3
    • ANDROID_HOME = /Volumes/RevBigData/rev_programs/rev_mac/rev_android/android_sdks/android_sdk
    • Java binary at: /Volumes/RevBigData/rev_programs/rev_mac/rev_dev/jdk-13.0.1.jdk/bin/java
    • Java version Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 13.0.1+9)
    ✗ Android license status unknown.
      Try re-installing or updating your Android SDK Manager.
      See https://developer.android.com/studio/#downloads or visit https://flutter.dev/setup/#android-setup for detailed instructions.

[!] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 8.2.1)
    • Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
    • Xcode 8.2.1, Build version 8C1002
    ✗ Flutter requires a minimum Xcode version of 10.2.0.
      Download the latest version or update via the Mac App Store.
    • CocoaPods version 1.8.4

[!] Android Studio (not installed)
    • Android Studio not found; download from https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html
      (or visit https://flutter.dev/setup/#android-setup for detailed instructions).

[✓] VS Code (version 1.41.0)
    • VS Code at /Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents
    • Flutter extension version 3.7.1

[✓] Connected device (1 available)
    • Redmi Note 4 • 322928570804 • android-arm64 • Android 7.0 (API 24)
```

and **`$ flutter run`** from **`cd my_app`** :

```
Launching lib/main.dart on Redmi Note 4 in debug mode...
Exception in thread "main" java.util.zip.ZipException: zip END header not found
        at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile$Source.zerror(ZipFile.java:1470)
        at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile$Source.findEND(ZipFile.java:1371)
        at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile$Source.initCEN(ZipFile.java:1378)
        at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile$Source.<init>(ZipFile.java:1209)
        at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile$Source.get(ZipFile.java:1172)
        at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile$CleanableResource.<init>(ZipFile.java:719)
        at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:239)     
        at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:169)     
        at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:183)     
        at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.unzip(Install.java:214)           
        at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.access$600(Install.java:27)       
        at org.gradle.wrapper.Install$1.call(Install.java:74)           
        at org.gradle.wrapper.Install$1.call(Install.java:48)           
        at org.gradle.wrapper.ExclusiveFileAccessManager.access(ExclusiveFileAccessManager.java:65)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.createDist(Install.java:48)       
        at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute(WrapperExecutor.java:128)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain.main(GradleWrapperMain.java:61)
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...                                  
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'... Done                         6.7s
Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

In short, I am unable to run my flutter app :

```
flutter create my_app  
cd my_app  
flutter run
```

Why is this so, and how can I get the app to run?

Thank you all in advance.

Comment: `flutter doctor` isn't showing checkmarks for either Android or iOS. You'll need at least one properly configured to build an app. Definitely accept the Android license. See: https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/macos#run-flutter-doctor

Comment: Thank you for the reply @MorrisonChang, but I have Android Studio installed. I read somewhere that `Flutter doctor` android studio unchecked is not necessary. Even that considered, I still get the same problem when I create and try running a simple project from inside Android Studio

Comment: Update your `flutter doctor` output with current version. Android toolchain should be all green.

Comment: I did that then tried `flutter run`. Same errors show. The app does not run

Comment: I just built and ran the flutter hello world app successfully. One difference is that I'm on the older OpenJDK 8 on a newer MacOS 10.14.6, but don't think that is the issue. I would though try building a copy of the hello world app in a different directory just to make sure it isn't any disk/storage/cache related issue.